# Use input() command while showing image using opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv, python-multithreading

I want to take input from user at the same time while displaying my image with opencv in python notebook. When the image is displaying in full screen, input command do not take input unless I minimize full screen and click on text bar to give input. I want to use input command while displaying image in full screen. Please see code

```py
import threading
import time
import glob
import cv2
def threadFunc():
    while True:
        for k in range(0,3):
            directory="/" + "*" + "." + "j" + "p" + "g"
            images = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob(directory)]
            for i in images:
                cv2.namedWindow("window", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
                cv2.setWindowProperty("window",cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
                cv2.imshow('window',i)
                cv2.waitKey(3000)
def main():
    th = threading.Thread(target=threadFunc)
    th.start()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        code_read=(input("Enter Number : "))
        print(code_read)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want to display images multiple images in folder one by one and store user input as response. for simplicity I just use print command.

Comment: What do you mean by "Python notebook"?  Python does not have that concept.  Are you running in Jupyter?  If so, you should say so AND add that tag.

Comment: @TimRoberts "I'm running in Jupyter" isn't a good reason to include the jupyter tag. Same for any other IDE. OP should either verify that his problem is indeed jupyter related (and THEN add the tag) or verify that the problem exists independent of jupyter (and then remove any jupyter related verbiage)

Comment: yes Jupyter notebook.

Comment: code is working without error in jupyter notebook. Maybe while i was writing code here it got messy.

Comment: You shouldn't *write* code here at all. You should *copy and paste* it from your IDE to here, so that we see the same code you see.